# how to insert into database with multiple array in php

Tags: php

hi guys can someone help me how to this. I have here the problems I can't solve it
for example

data for manny

```
 <input type="text" name="name[]" value="Manny" >

 <input type="text" name="course[]" value="BSIT" >
 <input type="text" name="level[]" value="2nd year" >

 <input type="text" name="course[]" value="BSCS" >
 <input type="text" name="level[]" value="3rd year" >

 <input type="text" name="course[]" value="BSENG" >
 <input type="text" name="level[]" value="4th year" >
```

data for Floyd

```
 <input type="text" name="name[]" value="Floyd" >

 <input type="text" name="course[]" value="ABM" >
 <input type="text" name="level[]" value="Grade 11" >

 <input type="text" name="course[]" value="STEM" >
 <input type="text" name="level[]" value="Grade 12" >
```

Manny hold 3 classes while Floyd hold 2 classes. so how can I insert it into database I guess use an array is suit for this problem but I don't know how. please help me with this

Comment: Please explain it better. Do you want to insert an array into the database? An array like this: `Array ( [Manny] => array(class1, class2, class3) [Floyd] => array(class1, class2) )`

Comment: exactly thats what I want..please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will make more sense to use an array if the structure "data for Manny" and "data for Floyd" are the same. Not like when you are having "GRADE" in "data for Floyd" and "YEAR" in "data for Manny".

Moreover, what exactly are you trying to achieve? You don't want to treat Manny and Floyd data separately?

You can have a check and see if this is going to help.

```
    Manny Data
        <input type="text" name="Manny[name]" value="Manny"><br>
        <select name="Manny[year1]">
            <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
        </select><br>

        <select name="Manny[year2]">
            <option value="BSCS">BSCS</option>
        </select><br>

        <select name="Manny[year3]">
            <option value="BSENG">BSENG</option>
        </select><br>


    Floyd Data
        <input type="text" name="Floyd[name]" value="Floyd"><br>
        <select name="Floyd[Grade 11]">
            <option value="ABM">ABM</option>
        </select><br>

        <select name="Floyd[Grade 12]">
            <option value="STEM">STEM</option>
        </select><br>
```

=====RESULT=====

```
    Array(
[Manny] => Array
    (
        [name] => Manny
        [year1] => BSIT
        [year2] => BSCS
        [year3] => BSENG
    )

[Floyd] => Array
    (
        [name] => Floyd
        [Grade 11] => ABM
        [Grade 12] => STEM
    )
)
```

$_POST["Manny"] contains all Manny's data.

$_POST["Floyd"] contains all Floyd's data.

Comment: I think it is possible to do it but I don't know how. it doesn't need to have a same value for "data for manny" and "data for Floyd"

Comment: Okay I just added some examples, hope it helps